# is there a way to automatically create a javascript object by just assigning a property?

Tags: javascript, perl

I am doing a project which requires to pass Perl objects to javascript via JSON. I am facing a problem in terms of "intermediate" object definition.

In Perl, object is represented by hash, and programmers don't have to define anything "in the middle". Once a property is created, all intermediate objects are automatically created as hash references. e.g.

```
$graph{chart}{yAxis}{title} = "Temperature Tracking";
```

However, once this object is passed to Javascript, if I want to add any new properties in the "intermediate" object, like:

```
graph.chart.xAxis.title = "Time Sequence";
```

I'll have an "undefined graph.chart.xAxis" error. Unlike Perl, Javascript doesn't automatically create objects if we simply assign a property for it.

At the moment I have to use below solution:

```
if (!graph.chart.xAxis) {
  graph.chart.xAxis = {};
  graph.chart.xAxis.title = "Time Sequence";
}
```

Unfortunately, in our project the objects passed from Perl are pretty dynamic and there are plenty of other objects that Javascript may not know. Above way makes JS code pretty lengthy and "ugly looking". Are there any better solutions to make Javascript behave like Perl, which means I don't have to create intermediate objects manually?

Comment: Well, you can simply write a small function that creates all the missing objects.

Comment: @Niko I am not sure, but javascript doesn't have autovivification, am I right? And how do you suppose this function checks of missing objects?

Comment: @Ioldop Please see answer below. You'll have to do this using strings though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this meets your requirements but a simple function to create the missing objects could look like this:

```js
function insertNode(obj, node, value) {
    var segments = node.split('.');
    var key = segments.pop();
    var ref = obj;

    while (segments.length > 0) {
        var segment = segments.shift();
        if (typeof ref[segment] != 'object') {
            ref[segment] = {};
        }
        ref = ref[segment];
    }

    ref[key] = value;
};

var x = {};
insertNode(x, 'foo.bar.baz', 'hello world');
alert(x.foo.bar.baz); // "hello world"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sNywt/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Niko. I made a few tests and your solution works fine. Now I understand there seems to be no built-in features in Javascript to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in a library called [steeltoe](https://github.com/jclem/steeltoe)

```
steelToe(graph).set('chart.xAxis.title', 'Time Sequence');
```

Comment: Great! This seems to be the most straightforward solution.

Answer (score 2):

not sure, if its suitable in your case, but you could check for property existence and create it if does not exist, like:

```
function use_or_create(obj, prop) {
   return (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))  ? true : (obj[prop] = {});
}
var graph.chart = {}; //your object
//function call to check if property exist before trying to use it
use_or_create(graph.chart, 'xAxis'); //check if xAxis exists and creates one if doesnot
graph.char.xAxis.title = "tested";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sudhir. This solution is much better than my original one, but I still need to test the existence of every nested object in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this `Object` extension will do:

```
Object.prototype.val = function(prop,val){
  prop = /\./i.test(prop) ? prop.split('.') : prop;
  if (prop.constructor === Array){
      var objnow = this, pr;
      while (pr = prop.shift()){
        if (!objnow[pr]){
            objnow[pr] = {};
        }
        if (!prop.length) {
            objnow[pr] = val;
        }
        objnow = objnow[pr];
      }
      for (var l in objnow){
          this[l] = objnow[l];
      }
  } else {
      this[prop] = val;
  }
}
// usage
var myO = {};
myO.val('a.b.c',3);        //=> myO.a.b.c = 3
myO.val('someprop',3);     //=> myO.someprop = 3
myO.val('a.b.someprop',5); //=> myO.a.b.someprop = 3
```